# css :nth-child() psuedo selecting

Tags: html, css

I have a multilanguage website.

On the left side of the website there is a navigation menu. The items in there are floated to left. But 1 item of the list (the second one) is floating too much to the left. I've tried to fix that using  `li:nth-child(2) psuedo` selecting. This all worked out well. But on the other pages (another language), the second item isn floated too much to the right.

Question:

Is there another way of styling only 1 element in a list without using inline css? (I don't have access to the html).

```css
.welcome80 .media-list .item-readmore {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<li class="">
  <a class="item-image" href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="">
    <img src="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/125x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/s/estwin_630x316.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <h2 class="item-name"><a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti">Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti</a></h2>
  <div class="item-desc">
    <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-readmore">
    <a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti">Lue lisää...&nbsp;&gt;</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Screenshot example:

https://i.gyazo.com/1bdbdc0831d970cbd4057170aa3d1339.png

As you can see the 2nd item is floated too much to the left.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and point out what exactly needs to change?

Comment: Does your HTML have any distinction at all for the languages? Like an attribute or a class on the HTML or BODY tag etc?

Comment: They use the same class in the HTML

Comment: you can use the `:nth-child()` selector as you've already mentioned, why does this not solve your problem?

Comment: If there is any distinction between the different language pages (at this element or in a parent) then it would be possible. Else, I don't think so.

Comment: Because if I use that on e.g. the english version, it all works well. But when I use it on e.g. the german version the second item also gets the pseudo stylesheet.

Comment: Each page has a different root? `<html lang='de'>`, `<html lang='en'>`

Comment: Without using javascript. You'll need **something** within the HTML to change so you can distinguish one rule from the other.

Comment: ah ok, well are there any attibutes/classes/id's in the html that change when you switch from english/german etc?

Comment: No they all stay the same. Magento translates them via a .csv file.

Comment: then you cannot change it using css.

Comment: Rather than trying to hack a solution for a single menu item into place, I suggest trying to figure out what the ACTUAL problem is that is causing the items not to line up in the first place. Please post the CSS and HTML for your menu.

Comment: Please provide full code that will allow us to reproduce the issue you are having. As commented by @J.Titus judging from the screenshot this would appear to be fixable without a hack.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the comments, it would appear that there will be no changes between the HTML making this an impossible task for CSS alone.

I would suggest using jQuery to get the value of the 'lang' attribute from your root element as you've mentioned that this **does** change.

**jQuery:**

```
$( 'html:first' ).attr( 'lang' )
```

This will return said 'lang' value which you could use to check if the page is English. You would then use the `.addClass()` method to add a class with specific styling to the offending element.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Hopefully this all helps. If you need more help with the script. Please let me know.

**EDIT:**

The question wasn't overly clear at the time of answering so this solution isn't the best fix for this situation. This *may* be of use to someone in the future so I will leave it posted.

Comment: i believe it has to do with float and text wrapping underneath ...

Comment: @GCyrillus I believe you could be right. I just had a quick scan of the comments and thought this might be helpful. Have upvoted your answer in an attempt to balance it out.. Appears to be the **proper** solution.

Comment: looks like it was it, the OP commented it's own answer and i definitely believe this is it :) . your answer is helpfull too , might not be in this very case, do not delete it . Maybe add a comment inside it about the non clarity of question when answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the two divs - `item-desc` and `item-readmore` with another div and apply `overflow-hidden`

```css
.welcome80 .media-list .item-readmore {
margin-top: 12px;
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
}
.item-text{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<li class="">
                                                        <a class="item-image" href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="">
                    <img src="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/125x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/s/estwin_630x316.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
                                <h2 class="item-name"><a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti">Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti</a></h2>
            <div class="item-text">
            <div class="item-desc">
                                        <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>                    </div>
            <div class="item-readmore">
                <a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti">Lue lisää...&nbsp;&gt;</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot tells me that your image is floatting, so text wrap underneath.

You may use a buffer to hold aside content and set it to overflow:hidden.

> **edit**: this is the clearest explanation i found in english about your trouble here : http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

see demo below, added backgrounds to see where elements stands :

```css
.welcome80 .media-list .item-readmore {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}
.item-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
 

/* fix */
.buffer {
  overflow:hidden;
  }

/* let's see */
* {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

```html
<li class="">
  <a class="item-image" href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="">
    <img src="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/125x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/s/estwin_630x316.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <h2 class="item-name"><a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti">Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti</a></h2>
  <div class="item-desc">
    <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>
    <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-readmore">
    <a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti">Lue lisää...&nbsp;&gt;</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a class="item-image" href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="">
    <img src="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/small_image/125x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/s/estwin_630x316.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="buffer">
    <h2 class="item-name"><a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti" title="Ericsson toteutti EstWin-projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti">FIX ME <br/>HERE</a></h2>
    <div class="item-desc">
      <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>
      <p>Viron EstWin-hankkeen tavoitteena on rakentaa optinen valokuituverkko kattamaan lähes koko Viro.&nbsp; Hankkeen urakoitsija Ericsson toteutti vuoden 2015 projektin TKF:n ACE-konseptin mukaisesti.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-readmore">
      <a href="http://www.ace-fibreoptic.com/index.php/news.html#ericsson-toteutti-estwin-projektin-tkf-n-ace-konseptin-mukaisesti">Lue lisää...&nbsp;&gt;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: **who ever downvoted , can you explain why ?** because to me here it seems obvious that the OP doesn't know yet how to deal with floatting elements

Answer (score 0):

Parent class of the list and :nth-child() selectors will work.

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out via a workaround. I made the containers where the link is stored a little big bigger (increased the width). And now they behave as expected.

Comment: ??  can you show us your fixed, maybe i missunderstood the question, (**who ever  downvoted or upvoted  can you explain why ?**)

Comment: I just made the container a little bit bigger, so it has more space. Now the link is floating as it should. I could also have it done by giving the image a padding-bottom of 30 px

Comment: okay, see this http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ so it helps you understand what's going on. when you have some trouble with positionning elements, you can add backgrounds so you see exactly where they stand in your page (borders might change the block formatting context , do not use it, but box-shadow will do instead)